# triyng run the crawler with docker image

Tags: algolia

I'm triyng run the crawler with docker image, but it's returning this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Santosgab\Desktop\documentation> docker run -it --env-file=.env -e "CONFIG=$(cat config.json | jq -r tostring)" algolia/docsearch-scraper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/src/config/config_loader.py", line 101, in _load_config
    data = json.loads(config, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 367, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

i used the config provided by Algolia, just made some small changes to run in my project, my config.json has no problem.

```
{
  "index_name": "Sequor",
  "sitemap_urls": ["http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml"],
  "sitemap_alternate_links": true,
  "stop_urls": ["/tests"],
  "selectors": {
    "lvl0": {
      "selector": "(//ul[contains(@class,'menu__list')]//a[contains(@class, 'menu__link menu__link--sublist menu__link--active')]/text() | //nav[contains(@class, 'navbar')]//a[contains(@class, 'navbar__link--active')]/text())[last()]",
      "type": "xpath",
      "global": true,
      "default_value": "Documentation"
    },
    "lvl1": "header h1",
    "lvl2": "article h2",
    "lvl3": "article h3",
    "lvl4": "article h4",
    "lvl5": "article h5, article td:first-child",
    "lvl6": "article h6",
    "text": "article p, article li, article td:last-child"
  },
  "strip_chars": " .,;:#",
  "custom_settings": {
    "separatorsToIndex": "_",
    "attributesForFaceting": ["language", "version", "type", "docusaurus_tag"],
    "attributesToRetrieve": [
      "hierarchy",
      "content",
      "anchor",
      "url",
      "url_without_anchor",
      "type"
    ]
  },
  "conversation_id": ["833762294"],
  "nb_hits": 46250
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I notice:

1. There's no path on your config file. Can you try it with pathing (i.e. `./config.json`)
2. Your config is missing any `start_urls` as entry points to crawling.